# How consume REST service to expose it in oData

Tags: rest, netweaver, sap-gateway, sap-smp

I have a REST service that I call from my client app. The service use JSON to manage data.

I want insert SAP NetWeaver Gateway between client and REST server to expose the **REST** data as **oData**.

The REST service have get and put methods to read and write data from/to db.

Now  I have to decide the way in which starting:

1. Translate data from/to REST server using **ABAP code** to serialize data in the *two ways* (get REST data and create oData in response to a url  get oData call  *and*  create the REST call in response to a url post oData call)
2. Use SMP - **SAP Mobile Platform** (Eclipse plugin) to write integration code (in javascript) to consume REST service in reading and writing exposing this service ad oData. http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/mobility-platform/blog/2015/04/08/integration-gateway-rest-data-source-overview-of-blogs

The 2nd solution seems to be the best way (no-require ABAP programming, use js high level language, parse-libs to manage oData and json ...) but i don't know if SMP was created to do this work.

And what is the result of the 2nd method? It seems to be a zip file (similar to a war) that I  can push to the SAP Gateway to deploy the integration-logic. Right? How can I test my code without deploy every time the zip on SAP Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to create a create Odata service in SAP Gateway and consume it in your app using SMP 3 or HCPms (SAP's mobile solution on cloud).

Use SMP SDK to consume the Odata service.